# Parametric bind answers

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'd like to create some access policy by bind and I'm wondering if is it possibile to setup dynamic/parametric lookup answers in bind per-client. Something like:

```
// Answer to nslookup example.com
if($client_ip == '192.168.1.10')
   return ('80.36.36.200');
else
   return ('127.0.0.1');
```

In alternative I could create a secondary bind instance using `-c secondary-bind-config.conf` on another interface but I'd like to have just an instance of bind running.

Comment: [group-policy]? Are you running `bind` on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use **view** statement

From [zytrax guide](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/view.html):

```
view "local" {
 match-clients { 192.168.1.10;};
  zone "example.com" {
   type master;
   file "example.com-80.36.etc";
  };
};


view "all" {
 match-clients { "any";};
  zone "example.com" {
   type master;
   file "example.com-127.etc";
  };
};
```

In one zone file you include one set of ips, in second file - another set.